# Needed help i C

Tags: c

Can anyone explain me how does this work?

```
void matr(int arr[max][max], int n, int m){

int i, k;
for (i = 0, k = m * n; i < k; i++)
{
    arr[i / m][i % m] = rand() % 10 * (pow(-1, rand() % 10));
}}
```

Comment: It sets the array elements randomly in the range `-9 <= value <= +9`

Comment: But it can be done without the `math.h` library more simply, with `rand() % 19 - 9`.

Comment: we are not really here to teach you the C language.  So this question is somewhat offtopic.   questions should be of the `help me, this does not compile` and `help me, this gives the wrong output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given this code:

```
void matr(int arr[max][max], int n, int m)
{

    int i;
    int k;

    for (i = 0, k = m * n; i < k; i++)
    {
        arr[i / m][i % m] = rand() % 10 * (pow(-1, rand() % 10));
    }
}
```

here is an explanation:

```
1) MAX must be a #define or enum value  
   cannot be sure of which as that detail was not posted

2) `int arr[max][max]` is a pointer to a 2D array
   with max rows and max columns

3) `int n, int m` we can assume are the number or rows and columns to be filled in
   unfortunately with such extremely poor/meaningless parameter names
   it is difficult to be sure of their meaning.
   Also, both 'n' and 'm' must be <= 'max'

4) `int k;` should really have been: `int k = m*n;`
   and that calculation not placed in the 'for() statement, first parameter.
   why the whole 2D matrix is not being filled is a good/unanswered question.

5) `for (i = 0, k = m * n; i < k; i++)`  means loop m*n times with loop counter 'i'

6) `arr[i / m][i % m]`  this is a calculation of which row/column
   to place the produced value into.
   notice that this fills the matrix a row at a time
   however, if 'm' is not equal to 'n' then this calculation is flawed

7) `rand() % 10` get a number in the range 0...9 inclusive

8) `rand() % 10)` get a number in the range 0...9 inclusive

9) `(pow(-1, rand() % 10)` get the -1 to the 0...9 (inclusive) power
   which will produce both positive and negative values 
   depending on if the 'power' value is even or odd
```